# Insert row on top in Google Sheet with API version 3

Tags: php, excel, google-sheets-api

I am trying to insert rows in google sheet with PHP application using Google Sheets API v3. I am able to insert row with the code explained here: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration#add_a_new_row_of_data

But with this the new rows are appended to the end of the specified sheet and I want that every new row should be inserted on top and other existing rows should shift down.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hello Jefer, kindly let me know - are you using/planning on using the Sheets v3 API or the v4 API? I am asking because the solution is be different for each... Thanks

Comment: Hi @carlesgg97 Thanks for the quick response. I am using Sheets v3 API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no trivial way of doing what you are trying to accomplish with Sheets v3 API. In order to insert a row in the topmost part of your sheet, you will have to:

1. Fetch all the data in the sheet (See: [retrieve a list-based feed](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/v3/data#retrieve_a_list-based_feed)).
2. Clear the sheet, or create a new one where the destination data will be placed.
3. Insert the first row (See: [add a list row](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/v3/data#add_a_list_row)).
4. Insert the rest of the data.

Bear in mind that this solution is not ideal, since the amount of data transferred can be really big (fetching the whole amount of cells and re-sending them), and for that same reason it may also take a considerable amount of time.

If you'd like to accomplish this feature more easily, kindly consider [migrating to Sheets v4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration).

Comment: Thank you for the descriptive answer. Can you please list the steps for the same problem using API V4.

Comment: I am asking it because I searched the documentation of V4 but there was no function to add a new row at the top of the file with new data.